# As restrict visible area of the map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

I can initialize the map in a specified coordinate but I need to restrict the size of the map so you can see and only a small part of it.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([23.047670, -81.560440], 13);

    L.tileLayer ('../tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
        minZoom: 12,
        maxZoom: 16
    }).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([0,0], {draggable:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the extent of your div that contains your map. If your div is called "map", you can use `CSS` like this:

```
 <style>  
  #map { height: 200px;
         width: 200px;
 }  
 </style>
```

Comment: No. I want the movement around the map is set for a specific area. No more.

Comment: Then you might want to have a look into the `maxBounds` option. See [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html)